# Remove unwanted spaces between quotations

Tags: python, regex, removing-whitespace

Is there a more elegant way to remove spaces between quotations (despite using code like this:

```
input = input.replace('" 12 "', '"12"')`)
```

from a sentence like this:

```
 At " 12 " hours " 35 " minutes my friend called me.
```

Thing is that numbers can change, and then the code won't work correctly. :)

Comment: Look into the built-in string method `strip()` :)

Comment: As @BuddyBob said, there are no commas in your string. Do you mean quotations?

Comment: `re.sub(r'" +?(.+?) +?"', '"\\1"', s)`

Comment: As long as your string have format `"  something  "`, spaces between quotations and something will be removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions as long as your quotations are reasonably sane:

```
re.sub(r'"\s*([^"]*?)\s*"', r'"\1"', input)
```

The pattern reads as "quote, any number of spaces, stuff that's not a quote (captured), followed by any number of spaces and a quote. The replacement is just the thing you captured in quotes.

Notice that the quantifier in the capture group is reluctant. That ensures that you don't capture the trailing spaces.

Comment: @Mark. Thanks for the catch. I also meant to write the expression more carefully. I'm comfortable with regex, but it's not my forte

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a regular expression, such as the one below:

`"\s+(.*?)\s+"`

This matches any substring of any length containing any character which is not a newline, surrounded by whitespace and quotation marks. By passing this to `re.compile()`, you can use the returned `Pattern` object to call the `sub()` method.

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = 'At " 12 " hours " 35 " minutes my friend called me.'
>>> regex = re.compile(r'"\s+(.*?)\s+"')
>>> regex.sub(r'"\1"', string)
'At "12" hours "35" minutes my friend called me.'
```

*The `\1` calls for the first group to be substituted, in this case the string matched by `.*?`*

Comment: Should technically be \s*, no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess it would work with `*` or with `+`, but I thought of `+` first.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I came up with real quick that will work for any numbers you input.

```
input = 'At " 12 " hours " 35 " minutes my friend called me.'

input = input.split()

for count, word in enumerate(input):
    if input[count] == '"':
        del input[count]
    if input[count].isdigit():
        input[count] = '"' + input[count] + '"'

str1 = ' '.join(input)
print('Output:')
print(str1)
```

Output:

```
>>> Output:
>>> At "12" hours "35" minutes my friend called me.
```